# Every dict value gets updated even tho i point at a specific key - PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

is this a bug or am I missing something?

Im iterating trough a list of topics with a for loop. In that loop i update a key in a premade dict with the value of another dict. This part is working fine.
So now i gave a payload dict with the new unit value in it and a topic string.
But the last step where i want to write a new dict with the topic as key and the whole payload as value does not really work, cause it always updates every value of the dict instead of just the one i point to.

Has anyone a idea what i am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Code:

```
for topic in self.topics:
                
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    payload['unit'] = units[topic]
    print(payload)
    print(topic)
    data[topic] = payload
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
1
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

2
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

3
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

4
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/StromFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/StromFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

5
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/SpannungFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/StromFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/SpannungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

6
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/FrequenzFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/StromFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/SpannungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/FrequenzFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

7
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/WirkleistungFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/StromFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/SpannungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/FrequenzFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/WirkleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

8
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/BlindleistungFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/StromFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/SpannungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/FrequenzFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/WirkleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/BlindleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

9
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}
/test/mqtt/snmp-ausgesch.Service
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/StromFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/SpannungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/FrequenzFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 
'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/WirkleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/BlindleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/snmp-ausgesch.Service': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}}

10
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/Alarm-Ausgang01
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/StromFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/SpannungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/FrequenzFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/WirkleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/BlindleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/snmp-ausgesch.Service': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Alarm-Ausgang01': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}

11
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}
/test/mqtt/T3-Bereit
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/StromFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/SpannungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/FrequenzFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 
'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/WirkleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/BlindleistungFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/snmp-ausgesch.Service': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/Alarm-Ausgang01': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/T3-Bereit': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You are pushing everything to the same data dictionary. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm gonna compare those payload values to messages sent over mqtt. So i need to access the format of an specific payload over the dict and compare it with the incomming message.
I want every payload value with its matching unit in the dict. But it always updates every value and not just the one i point at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to understand what you need. Does this give you the output you expect?

```
topics = ['/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1', '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2', '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32']
payload = {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': True}
units = {'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': 'V', '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': 'Vu', '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': 'A'}

counter = 0
data = {}

for topic in topics:
                
    counter += 1
    print("\n")
    print(counter)
    payload_copy = payload.copy()
    payload_copy['unit'] = units[topic]
    print(payload_copy)
    print(topic)
    data[topic] = payload_copy
    print(data)
```

Last output:
3

{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'A'}
/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'A'}}

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to test it on an small example:

```
topics = ['/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1', '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2', '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32']
payload = {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': True}
units = {'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': 'V', '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': 'Vu', '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': 'A'}

counter = 0
data = {}

for topic in topics:
                
    counter += 1
    print("\n")
    print(counter)
    payload['unit'] = units[topic]
    print(payload)
    print(topic)
    data[topic] = payload
    print(data)
```

What i get:

```
1
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}


2
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}
/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}}


3
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'A'}
/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'A'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'A'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'A'}}
```

What i want:

```
1
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}
/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}}


2
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}
/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}}


3
{'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'A'}
/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32
{'/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten1': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'V'}, '/test/mqtt/Hilfsknoten2': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'Vu'}, '/test/mqtt/RaumtemperaturFP32': {'value': 'float', 'timestamp': 'iso8601', 'unit': 'A'}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).